# how to get the String value of attribute id="@+id/name" in android

Tags: android, xml

I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UrlConfig
   ...>

    <Node
        id="@+id/api_msg_list"
        url="..." />

</UrlConfig>
```

in my url.xml in xml folder,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8Xxi.png)

when i was using Android Studio 2.2 and buildTool 22.0.0 , and execute

```
String idAttr = xmlParser.getAttributeValue(null,"id");
```

the `idAttr` was `"@+id/api_msg_list"`.

```
final XmlResourceParser xmlParser = context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.url);
        int eventCode;
        try {
            eventCode = xmlParser.getEventType();
            while (eventCode != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                switch (eventCode) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        if ("UrlConfig".equals(xmlParser.getName())) {

                                   ...

                        } else if ("Node".equals(xmlParser.getName())) {

                            String idAttr = xmlParser.getAttributeValue(null,"id");
                            if (idAttr.startsWith("@+id/")){
                    ...
                }
                                   ...
                        }
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                eventCode = xmlParser.next();
            }
    }
```

But after i updated Android Studio to 3.0 and buildTool to 26.0.2 this morning,

the `idAttr` turns to `"@123456.."`，so it can't get into the `if` anymore.

My question is how can i still get the pure String value of id like `"@+id/api_msg_list"` instead of the int value like `"@123456..."` which was auto turned into as R file,Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more code so that we all can see how are you trying to access this resource?

Comment: i added some now

Comment: Use `String idAttr = new String(xmlParser.getAttributeValue(null,"id"));`

Comment: @Ghulam Moinul Quadir still get "@2131230849"

Comment: Please see the following tutorial,http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/xml/android-simple-xmlpullparser-tutorial/